# Check whether user is in django_db or no

Tags: python, django-models, django-urls, django-database, chatroom

I have the django model called "create-chat" and there I write names of people I want to see in a group chat.
So. I created the model, but I don't know how to make a condition whether user is in django_db or no,  if so then I want to show them the button "join chat"
And after clicking the button he will be transferred to the url sitename.com/lobby/1
Now I have the view that shows the page /lobby/any_number 
First of all I'd to block these pages from users and only if the user is in django_db 
He is able to visit the page Lobby/1
ONLY THE lobby/1 not lobby/2
I don't ask you to do it, I just want you to explain me how to do it, or maybe advice me some articles about my problem.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQw4Y.jpg

..1). How to block all users for visiting this url sitename.com/1234 <- here goes any number u d liked. ( 4 characters ) 
So now I blocked all the users for visiting this page, and how now make it visible for a certain users/user?

Comment: what is `django_db`, is it a specific model in your website ?

Comment: No, too lazy to write name of my model, in model.py I have the model called makechat

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are storing the information in User object.

> usr = User.objects.get(username = whateveristheusername)
>
> if usr is not None:
>
> #User Exist. Click to join chat
>
> else:
>
> #Create User or any other viable functionality

Comment: I will draw my db and what I want from you.
To make sure you understand me. Wait a min.

Comment: I need to make a condition ( if logged in user, if his username is in chat model then he will receive the button

Comment: And how to block all users from lobby/any_number page, I want to show the page only for users which usernames are in the db can be redirected to lobby/1 after clicking the button

Comment: You have to put the condition in template like {% if userAvail %} #do_something. You need to pass this userAvail value from your views.py to template using  context. Additionally, you can also make use of request.session

Comment: Okay, I will try it.